# Appstream 2.0 failing to pass session context

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-appstream

We are running an Appstream 2.0 instance, and are trying to run the [example in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appstream2/latest/developerguide/managing-stacks-fleets.html) to run an instance of Chrome and launch a default URL passed in through the AWS CLI.

We have successfully generated the URL using the CLI and this command:

```
aws appstream create-streaming-url --stack-name "stack-name-here" --fleet-name "fleet-name-here" --user-id "user-email@email.com" --application-id "Chrome" --session-context "www.google.com"
```

But upon launching, the session context "www.google.com" is never passed. We have set up a batch file with the reference to SessionContextRetriever.exe as specified in the documentation on the image.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (`C:\Scripts\SessionContextRetriever.exe`) do (
set var=%%f
)
chrome.exe %var%
pause
```

We're also pretty sure that the context is actually getting passed in through URL generation, as it shows up in a URL parameter. The problem is, chrome launches and just goes right to the new tab page, ignoring the session context.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody running into this problem, the documentation uses the wrong quotes.

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('C:\Scripts\SessionContextRetriever.exe') do (
set var=%%f
)
chrome.exe %var%
pause

Instead of ` use '.